# how to get the number of weeks of current year using Zend_Date class

Tags: php, zend-framework, date, zend-date

how can we get number of weeks of current year,

for example if it's 2009 there are 53 weeks and 2010 has 52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can try setting the date to 31st Dec of current year, and querying the week number?